# Python Thread Pool Faster than Go Routines when Scanning AWS S3?

Tags: python, go, amazon-s3, concurrency

I have recently been digging into understanding Golang concurrency, in particular the use of channels and worker pools.  I wanted to compare performance between Go and Python (as many have done) because I have mostly read that Go outperforms Python with regard to concurrency.  So I wrote two programs to scan an AWS account's S3 buckets and report back the total size.  I performed this on an account that had more the 75 buckets totaling more than a few TB of data.

I was surprised to find that my Python implementation was nearly 2x faster than my Go implementation.  This confuses me based on all the benchmarks and literature I have read.  This leads me to believe that I did not implement my Go code correctly.  While watching both programs run I noticed that the Go implementation only used up to 15% of my CPU while Python used >85%.  Am I missing an important step with Go or am I missing something in my implementation?  Thanks in advance!

**Python Code:**

```py
'''
Get the size of all objects in all buckets in S3
'''
import os
import sys
import boto3
import concurrent.futures

def get_s3_bucket_sizes(aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key, aws_session_token=None):

    s3client = boto3.client('s3')

    # Create the dictionary which will be indexed by the bucket's
    # name and has an S3Bucket object as its contents
    buckets = {}

    total_size = 0.0

    #
    # Start gathering data...
    #

    # Get all of the buckets in the account
    _buckets = s3client.list_buckets()

    cnt = 1
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=50) as executor:
        future_bucket_to_scan = {executor.submit(get_bucket_objects, s3client, bucket): bucket for bucket in _buckets["Buckets"]}

        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_bucket_to_scan):
            bucket_object = future_bucket_to_scan[future]

            try:
                ret = future.result()
            except Exception as exc:
                print('ERROR: %s' % (str(exc)))
            else:
                total_size += ret

    print(total_size)

def get_bucket_objects(s3client, bucket):

    name = bucket["Name"]

    # Get all of the objects in the bucket
    lsbuckets = s3client.list_objects(Bucket=name)

    size = 0
    while True:
        if "Contents" not in lsbuckets.keys():
            break

        for content in lsbuckets["Contents"]:            
            size += content["Size"]

        break

    return size

#
# Main
#
if __name__=='__main__':
    get_s3_bucket_sizes(os.environ.get("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"), os.environ.get("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"))
```

**Go Code:**

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/awserr"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3"
)

type S3_Bucket_Response struct {
    bucket string
    count  int64
    size   int64
    err    error
}

type S3_Bucket_Request struct {
    bucket string
    region string
}

func get_bucket_objects_async(wg *sync.WaitGroup, requests chan S3_Bucket_Request, responses chan S3_Bucket_Response) {

    var size  int64
    var count int64

    for request := range requests {
        bucket := request.bucket
        region := request.region

        // Create a new response
        response := new(S3_Bucket_Response)
        response.bucket = bucket

        sess, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
            Region: aws.String(region), 
        })

        s3conn := s3.New(sess)

        resp, err := s3conn.ListObjectsV2(&s3.ListObjectsV2Input{
            Bucket: aws.String(bucket),
        })

        if err != nil {
            if awsErr, ok := err.(awserr.Error); ok {

                switch awsErr.Code() {
                case "NoSuchBucket":
                    response.err = fmt.Errorf("Bucket: (%s) is NoSuchBucket.  Must be in process of deleting.", bucket)
                case "AccessDenied":
                    response.err = fmt.Errorf("Bucket: (%s) is AccessDenied.  You should really be running this with full Admin Privaleges", bucket)
                }
            } else {
                response.err = fmt.Errorf("Listing Objects Unhandled Error: %s ", err)
            }

            responses <- *response
            continue
        } 

        contents := resp.Contents
        size      = 0
        count     = 0

        for i:=0; i<len(contents); i++ {
            size  += *contents[i].Size
            count += 1
        }

        response.size  = size
        response.count = count

        responses <- *response
    }

    wg.Done()
}

func main() {

    var err  error
    var size int64
    var resp *s3.ListBucketsOutput
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    sess, _ := session.NewSession()
    s3conn  := s3.New(sess)

    // Get account bucket listing
    if resp, err = s3conn.ListBuckets(&s3.ListBucketsInput{});err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error listing buckets: %s", err)
        return 
    }

    buckets := resp.Buckets
    size = 0

    // Create the buffered channels
    requests  := make(chan S3_Bucket_Request , len(buckets))
    responses := make(chan S3_Bucket_Response, len(buckets))

    for i := range buckets {

        bucket := *buckets[i].Name

        resp2, err := s3conn.GetBucketLocation(&s3.GetBucketLocationInput{                                                           
            Bucket: aws.String(bucket),                                                                                                       
        })         

        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Could not get bucket location for bucket (%s): %s", bucket, err)
            continue
        }

        wg.Add(1)
        go get_bucket_objects_async(&wg, requests, responses)

        region := "us-east-1"
        if resp2.LocationConstraint != nil {
            region = *resp2.LocationConstraint
        }

        request := new(S3_Bucket_Request)
        request.bucket = bucket
        request.region = region

        requests <- *request        
    }

    // Close requests channel and wait for responses
    close(requests)
    wg.Wait()
    close(responses)

    cnt := 1
    // Process the results as they come in
    for response := range responses {

        fmt.Printf("Bucket: (%s) complete!  Buckets remaining: %d\n", response.bucket, len(buckets)-cnt)

        // Did the bucket request have errors?
        if response.err != nil {
            fmt.Println(response.err)
            continue
        }

        cnt  += 1
        size += response.size
    }

    fmt.Println(size)
    return 
}
```

Comment: as for me it may not be good place for your question. Maybe ask on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: It's exceedingly unlikely that goroutines vs. thread pool is the issue here, because accessing buckets in the cloud is vastly slower than any local scheduling done by Go or the OS for threads. Did you try to compare the performance for listing/scanning objects in a *single* bucket? E.g. what ever you did but without concurrency at all? It may be that the S3 Go API is slow for some reason, or maybe you're not using it correctly.

Comment: @EliBendersky I first tried without concurrency and it was much slower.  If this is truly a latency issue with accessing via the cloud and not goroutines vs thread pool then that answer is fine with me.  I just wasn't sure so I wanted to ask the question.

Comment: @furas thanks for the advice.  I will post the question there.

Comment: @loudcrowd: if w/o concurrency the Go method was slower than the Python method - this is where you ought to start. They should behave exactly the same because that cloud latency is large compared to whatever language runs it locally. It may be that you're using the Go API wrong, or may be just that it has an issue that should be raised in its bug tracker, etc.

Comment: Are you confident both are correct? Do both solutions return the same # of bytes and does that match what aws S3 console says?

Comment: This article says the boto s3 client is *not* threadsafe but haven't confirmed it by auditing the code https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/cw9mvh/how_safe_is_boto3_or_botocore_with_threads_that/

Comment: My first question would be: is each solution correct and can you prove it? My second thought would be to audit your code an ensure that the concurrent structure is the same, i.e. summing on main thread, same pool sizes, same amount of IO work per worker. My next thought wouuld be to audit defaults of the clients, i.e. does python have a default connection pool size? Go doesn't so it will create connections per request (i just ran into this last week :p)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry haven't had an opportunity to fully review this but my answer would be: **the solutions don't appear to be equivalent in terms of concurrency**. 3 things pop out:

- Thread safety of boto s3 client. Is this thread safe? Can you confirm it? [This reddit article](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/cw9mvh/how_safe_is_boto3_or_botocore_with_threads_that/) suggests that it is *not* threadsafe.
- Python is using a worker pool size of 50 but go is unbounded. ([a semphore could be used](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#channels) to add an upper bound of 50 to the current code)
- I"m not super familiar with boto but it looks like go is performing an additional IO call on the main thread for each bucket (`GetBucketLocation`) when compared to python.

My next questions would be:

- Is each solution correct and can you prove it? (do both sum to the same amount of bytes and do those match the s3 console?)
- Are you sure that the concurrent structure is the same,
  i.e. summing on main thread, same pool sizes, same amount of IO work
  per worker.
- Are the defaults of the clients equivalent?, i.e. does python have a default connection pool size? [Go doesn't so it will create connections per request](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/v1/developer-guide/custom-http.html) (i just ran into this last week)

Comment: Both versions yield the same results (same number of bytes).  I think you raise some good questions that might help explain why I am seeing different results.  I am not sure if the concurrent structure is the same and on the default pool size for Python.  Initially, since I am new to Go, I was wondering if I had something obviously wrong in my Go implementation.  It looks like I need to spends some more time investigating.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple answer.

When iterating over the buckets in go, just start go routines.

Furthermore, you can use delimiter to implement a breath-first listing of the buckets where new folders are fetched with new go-routines.

Together, this should give you a good speedup.